# Efficient Algorithm to Replace All SubArrays with Other SubArrays

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, replaceall

I have a byte array(can get very large, past 32 million bytes), and I need to replace some subarrays that with other subarrays of the same length. 
My current approach is search the byte array for all the subarrays I need to replace, every time I find one add the index of the subarray to a list, and continue.
My code is as follows. I have a nagging feeling that this cannot be efficient, because 32 million bytes is taking greater than 10 seconds to finish searching and replacing. I pass it 8 strings to replace, so it basically ends up searching for 16 subarrays.

Anyone see either any flaws with my algorithm or a more efficient one?

P.S. I don't actually replace them in this code, just find the indices. My code for that should be perfectly efficient.

```
 public class Search
{
    public List<int> positions;
    public List<int> lengths;
    private List<byte[]> stringsToSearchFor;
    public Search(List<string> strings){
        stringsToSearchFor = new List<byte[]>();
        positions = new List<int>();
        lengths = new List<int>();
        foreach (string tempString in strings){
            stringsToSearchFor.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tempString));
            stringsToSearchFor.Add(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(tempString));
        }
    }

    public void SearchBytes(byte[] haystack){
        int[] arrayOfInt = new int[stringsToSearchFor.Count];
        bool[] arrayOfBoolean = new bool[stringsToSearchFor.Count];
        for (var i = 0; i < haystack.Length; i++){
            byte currentByte = haystack[i];
            for (int stringCounter = 0; stringCounter < arrayOfBoolean.Length; stringCounter++)
            {
                byte[] stringLookFor = stringsToSearchFor.ElementAt(stringCounter);
                byte currentStringByte = stringLookFor[arrayOfInt[stringCounter]];
                //Saying the current byte is the desired one
                if (currentStringByte == currentByte)
                {
                    if (arrayOfInt[stringCounter] + 1 == stringLookFor.Length){
                        positions.Add(i - stringLookFor.Length + 1);
                        lengths.Add(stringLookFor.Length);
                        arrayOfInt[stringCounter] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arrayOfInt[stringCounter]++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    arrayOfInt[stringCounter] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }



}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? If it does work but you like to have a review. try: [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Everytime you call `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(` which will create a new array of bytes.. The most performance issues are memory allocations in your case.

Comment: A performance boost could be checking the first and the last character of the `stringsToSearchFor` in the haystack. If the character at `currentIndex + stringsToSearchFor.Length-1` isn't the last character. you can skip the current.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Not quite sure what you mean by that. stringsToSearchFor isn't just a byte[], it's a list of byte[]. I need a byte[] when I call Encoding.ASCII.getBytes() because I need to search for it. What do you mean? I don't think the limiting factor is memory allocations because it runs in about a millisecond if the byte[] is 4096 bytes long.

Answer (score 3):

I can tell from the fact that `SearchBytes()` only has 2 nested `for` loops that this brute-force search algorithm has a bug.  A brute-force search of this kind needs 3 nested loops: for each starting position within the haystack, for each needle string, you need a loop to check whether the entire needle appears at that position in the haystack.  (This innermost loop may abort early if it finds a character mismatch.)

Here's a concrete example: If the haystack is `ABCABCABD` and one of your needle strings is `ABCABD`, this string will not be found, despite the fact that it does occur.  That's because as soon as your algorithm sees the second `C` in the haystack, it will conclude that it must start looking for the needle from the *current* position in the haystack, when in fact it needs to start looking from an earlier position.

Anyway, the time complexity of brute-force for searching for a single length-m needle string in a length-n haystack string is O(nm), which is pretty terrible if both are moderately long.  [John Kurlak suggested Knuth-Morris-Pratt or Rabin-Karp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41434615/47984), and running either of these will certainly speed things up (as well as *be correct* :-P) if you are looking for a few large strings, but the algorithm that specifically targets efficiently finding *multiple* strings in a string is called the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm).  It takes time O(n+s+k), where n is the haystack size, s is the sum of the sizes of the needle strings to search for, and k is the number of occurrences of any needle string -- which is pretty hard to beat.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically doing a brute force search. Instead of doing brute force, you could do something more akin to the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) or [Rabin-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) string searching algorithms (but instead of searching for character sequences in strings, you're searching for byte sequences in arrays).